# Online platform control (proxy)

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

To connect to the online platform of the company I work for, I have to use a proxy. Is it possible for the person responsible for this platform to check if I am currently using other programs in addition to the browser with the open platform? Can they check or detect it anyway? I am using my own laptop.

Comment: You have to install something on your laptop? If so, what permissions does it require?

Comment: No, I don't need to install anything. All I have to do is set/enter the appropriate address in: control panel> configure proxy server> connections> LAN settings> use automatic configuration script and log into platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external proxy will only see the traffic running through it. It will only know what programs you are running based on the traffic. Unless it also inspects the traffic, it will not know what browser is being used.

Any proxy program you install, however, might monitor your machine and know a lot more.

Comment: As I said, only if that program generates traffic and that traffic goes through the proxy.